# Initiate Pycharm remote debugging from remote side

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging, django-manage.py

Is it possible to start remote debugging from the remote server?

**Example**: I have a django manage command I want to debug in my pycharm and running the manage command from pycharm doesn't do it in debugging.

Or is it possible to debug manage.py commands from pycharm remotely?

Comment: have you tried that: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python-remote-debug-server.html

Comment: Awesome. I will have to give that a try.